# Call over an external phone

Tags: applications, voip

I have a business sim card with an Android phone. Now different employees have to make calls, we all work from home. Right now we switch the sim to the person who is working. I would like them to be able to log on to the phone over data/wifi and make the calls. Does anybody know a location

I have been looking for this a few weeks but cannot find a solution except GoIP + a PBX. All solutions I found for this are a bit too complicated for the time I want to invest in this.

Comment: This post is not a solution for my question. Airdroid can initiate the call, but the audio is still on the device itself. I need the audio to be redirected to the person who initiated the call.